# Cannot see pictures on Trascend SD

Tags: nautilus, sd-card, shotwell

I m quite new to Ubuntu/Unix systems and I am facing some problems while trying to read files from my sd card. Basically the sd card is detected and mounted but I cannot see thumbnails or the content of jpeg/raw files.

I formatted the card on my camara (Nikon) and I've just kept one file in it, a simple jpg picture. Even using shotwell, I can explore the folder but I cannot see the thumbnail nor the content of the picture. However the picture can be seen correctly on my tablet.

Also, if I download a jpg image and I store it into any folder I can correctly see the thumbnail and the preview works correctly.

More details, `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disco /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 30401 cilindros, 488397168 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x00009b75

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1   *        2048   480337919   240167936   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       480339966   488396799     4028417    5  Extendida
/dev/sda5       480339968   488396799     4028416   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disco /dev/mmcblk0: 16.1 GB, 16130244608 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 1961 cilindros, 31504384 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x00000000

   Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192    31504383    15748096    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Also, in the folder properties I can see the field file system with value 'msdos'. This does not sound really good...

Any suggestion? 
Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`. and what filesystem is in use on the SD card?

Comment: Turned out wifi card provided some sort of http server so I managed to access sd card contents through http and could get pictures downloaded on my laptop.